# Unable to access Scala's Akka libraries in JRuby

Tags: scala, akka, jruby

I'm using `jruby 1.7.12 (1.9.3p392)` and I want to take advantage of the Scala Akka library. I'm aware of the Mikka gem, but I want to do this manually.

I've downloaded the Akka library "2.3.8" from http://akka.io/downloads/ (specifically the link "Akka 2.3.8 distribution for Scala 2.11").

Below is the file structure (one `app.rb` JRuby file and the rest is the downloaded Akka library)...

```
├── akka-2.3.8
|   ├── bin
|   ├── config
|   ├── deploy
|   ├── doc
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── akka
│   │   │   ├── akka-actor_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-agent_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-camel_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-cluster_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-contrib_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-dataflow_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-durable-mailboxes-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-file-mailbox_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-kernel_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-mailboxes-common_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-multi-node-testkit_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-persistence-experimental_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-persistence-tck-experimental_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-remote-tests_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-remote_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-slf4j_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-testkit_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-transactor_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── akka-zeromq_2.11-2.3.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── camel-core-2.10.3.jar
│   │   │   ├── config-1.2.1.jar
│   │   │   ├── guava-12.0.jar
│   │   │   ├── hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
│   │   │   ├── hawtjni-runtime-1.8.jar
│   │   │   ├── jna-3.0.9.jar
│   │   │   ├── jnr-constants-0.8.2.jar
│   │   │   ├── jsr305-1.3.9.jar
│   │   │   ├── junit-4.11.jar
│   │   │   ├── leveldb-0.5.jar
│   │   │   ├── leveldb-api-0.5.jar
│   │   │   ├── leveldbjni-1.7.jar
│   │   │   ├── leveldbjni-all-1.7.jar
│   │   │   ├── leveldbjni-linux32-1.5.jar
│   │   │   ├── leveldbjni-linux64-1.5.jar
│   │   │   ├── leveldbjni-osx-1.5.jar
│   │   │   ├── leveldbjni-win32-1.5.jar
│   │   │   ├── leveldbjni-win64-1.5.jar
│   │   │   ├── netty-3.8.0.Final.jar
│   │   │   ├── protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
│   │   │   ├── scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar
│   │   │   ├── scala-reflect-2.11.0.jar
│   │   │   ├── scala-stm_2.11-0.7.jar
│   │   │   ├── scalatest_2.11-2.1.3.jar
│   │   │   ├── slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
│   │   │   ├── uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar
│   │   │   └── zeromq-scala-binding_2.11-0.0.7-spark.jar
│   │   └── scala-library-2.11.4.jar
│   └── src
│       └── akka
│           ├── akka-actor_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-agent_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-camel_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-cluster_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-contrib_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-dataflow_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-durable-mailboxes-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-file-mailbox_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-kernel_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-mailboxes-common_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-multi-node-testkit_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-persistence-experimental_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-persistence-tck-experimental_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-remote-tests_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-remote_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-slf4j_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-testkit_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           ├── akka-transactor_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
│           └── akka-zeromq_2.11-2.3.8-sources.jar
└── app.rb
```

The contents of the `app.rb` file is...

```
require "java"

$CLASSPATH << "akka-2.3.8"
$: << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "akka-2.3.8")

java_import java.lang.System
java_import "akka.actor.ActorRegistry"
java_import "akka.actor.Actors"
java_import "akka.actor.UntypedActor"
```

...I appreciate that (in JRuby) `$CLASSPATH` and the load path `$:` are mapped, but I thought I would try both.

Running `app.rb` causes the following error (importing `java.lang.System` is fine, the `akka.actor.ActorRegistry` is the first line that breaks)...

```
NameError: cannot load Java class akka.actor.ActorRegistry
         for_name at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:1250
  get_proxy_class at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:34
      java_import at file:/Users/markmcdonnell/.rubies/jruby-1.7.12/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:26
              map at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2409
      java_import at file:/Users/markmcdonnell/.rubies/jruby-1.7.12/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:22
           (root) at size.rb:7
```

What is the problem here. Have I not downloaded the right files or am I not referencing them properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `<<` does not add all the individual jars to the classpath? You might have to look for something else to include all jars in lib and lib/akka. Unfortunately I don't know enough JRuby to tell you how to do it.

Also: you are importing classes (ActorRegistry, Actors) that don't exist in Akka 2.3.8. Please check the latest API docs, and make sure you are not trying an Akka 1.x example (as ActorRegistry would indicate).

So, the following seems to work, maybe you can use that as a starting point:

```
require "java"

$CLASSPATH << "akka-2.3.8/lib/scala-library-2.11.4.jar"
$CLASSPATH << "akka-2.3.8/lib/akka/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.8.jar"
$CLASSPATH << "akka-2.3.8/lib/akka/config-1.2.1.jar"

java_import java.lang.System
java_import "akka.actor.ActorRef"
java_import "akka.actor.ActorSystem"
java_import "akka.actor.Props"
java_import "akka.actor.UntypedActor"
```

Comment: thank you. This worked for me. I think the problem must have been a combination of using an older example from the book I'm reading (Programming Concurrency on the JVM) and not loading the correct libraries. Out of interest how do you know what jars are used by the java_imports (e.g. you've loaded `akka/config-x.x.x.jar` but not sure why)?

Comment: You're welcome. 

The minimal dependency for Akka is akka-actor and its dependencies, and I think it only depends on the Scala library and Typesafe config. Maybe slf4j/logback for LoggingActor.

It will get more complicated if you add remoting, cluster, persistence etc. because of transitive dependencies. That's why everyone uses automated dependency management (by means of maven or ivy) in the Java world, don't know how that translates to JRuby.

Comment: No, wait, that's ActorLogging, not LoggingActor.